# Tkinte: loop through image objects and set itemconfigure

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a bunch of OVALS. And have defined a variable (w_oval) to be used in a FOR. Itemconfigure does not accept this variable.  Something about immutable variables? How do I define a variable for the itemconfigure? I know I'm missing some philosophy here.

```
b1_oval = bottom_frame.create_oval( 25,180,65,205, fill='')
b2_oval = bottom_frame.create_oval( 25,180,65,205, fill='')
#... more bn_oval

i_oval = 0
w_oval = ''
ovalLONG = [-90,-75,-60,-45,-30,-15,0,15,30,45,60,75,90]
for j in ovalLONG:
    i_oval = i_oval + 1
    w_oval = str('b'+str(i_oval)+'_oval') # Not flying Wilbur
    if i == j:
           bottom_frame.itemconfigure(w_oval, fill='goldenrod3')
```

Comment: This is simply not how variables work. Store your ovals in a list or dictionary.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. But why does itemconfigure not accept a formated 
string? 
Works:
b2_oval = bottom_frame.create_oval( 75,180,115,205, fill='')
bottom_frame.itemconfigure(b2_oval, fill='goldenrod3')

Why does this formatted string  not?                    
w_oval = 'b'+str(i_oval)+'_oval'
bottom_frame.itemconfigure(w_oval, fill='goldenrod3')

Comment: itemformat _does_ accept a formatted string. The `itemconfigure` is working, but the string you're computing isn't associated with anything in the canvas.  It looks the same as the variable name, but it's just a string. The canvas has no idea that you've stored the id of an object in a variable with a name that matches the string.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line of code:

```
b1_oval = bottom_frame.create_oval( 25,180,65,205, fill='')
```

In the above code, `create_oval` is returning an integer identifier which represents the object that was created. You are storing this in a variable named `b1_oval`.

Now consider this code:

```
for j in ovalLONG:
    i_oval = i_oval + 1
    w_oval = str('b'+str(i_oval)+'_oval') # Not flying Wilbur
    if i == j:
           bottom_frame.itemconfigure(w_oval, fill='goldenrod3')
```

First, you are creating a *string* that looks like `"b1_oval"`. You are storing this string in a variable named `w_oval`. In other words, it's no different than if you did `w_oval = "b1_oval"`.

When you call `itemconfigure(w_oval, ...)` it is identical to calling `itemconfigure("b1_oval", ...).

That first parameter is taken by the canvas to be a tag or an id. Since it's not an integer it is treated as a tag. You have not created any objects on the canvas with the tag `"b1_oval", so nothing has changed. Just to be clear: tags and variable names are two completely different things.

You have one of two options: either give each oval a tag that matches that pattern (via the `tag` option), or store the ids in a way that you can use in the loop.

The second of those solutions is the best and easiest in my opinion. Instead of creating a bunch of variables that have numbers in the name, store the ids in a list or dictionary. Then it's just a simple lookup, without having to compute the name of a variable.

For example:

```
ovals = []
ovals.append(bottom_frame.create_oval(...))
ovals.append(bottom_frame.create_oval(...))
...
for j in ovalLONG:
    if i == j:
        bottom_frame.itemconfigure(ovals[i], ...)
```

I doubt the above is exactly what you want, because I don't know where you're computing `i` -- it's not in the code you provided. Still, the point is that you save the object ids in a list rather than trying to compute a variable name.

The main disadvantage to using lists is that you can't control the indexes. Lists always start counting at zero, so the first oval you create will always be `ovals[0]` even if you want to start the counting at `1`.

Another option is to use a dictionary rather than a list, which lets you use any arbitrary names or numbers for the ovals, and doesn't require that they are linear.

```
ovals = {}
ovals[1] = bottom_frame.create_oval(...)
ovals[100] = bottom_frame.create_oval(...)
...
i = 100
...
bottom_frame.itemconfigure(ovals[i], ...)
```